# 'command not found' error when running shell script

Tags: linux, shell-script

```
#!/bin/bash
# pre.sh revision 4.0.0  Date: 2011/12/24

### Path ###
FASTAR_DIR=$(cd $(dirname $0);pwd)

##### Function s #####
. ${FASTAR_DIR}/"script.func"

usage(){
  echo "Usage: " $COMNAME " [option]"
  echo "  option   : <NONE> ...... by 1 process"
  echo "             -n <CPUs> ... batch process by <CPUs> process"
  echo "             -all ........ batch process"
  echo "             -e .......... use exact wall distance mode"
  echo "             -metis ...... use pre-fastar metis version"
  echo "             -fsi ........ use pre-fastar metis version with FSI mode"
  echo "             -emetis ..... use pre-fastar metis version with exact wd mode"
  echo "             -efsi ....... use pre-fastar metis version with FSI and exact wd mode"
  echo "             -h .......... show this statement"
}

##### Function e #####

#======================================#
# Main                                 #
#======================================#
#=== initialize ===#
COMNAME=`basename $0`
set_variables
if [ $# -eq 1 ]; then
  case $1 in
    "-all" | "-e" | "-metis" | "-fsi" | "-emetis" | "-efsi") opt=$1      ;;
                                                       "-h") usage; exit ;;
                                                          *) usage; exit ;;
  esac
  cpu=1
elif [ $# -eq 2 ]; then
  case $1 in
    "-n") opt=$1      ;;
       *) usage; exit ;;
  esac
  if [ $2 -ge 1 ]; then
    cpu=$2
  else
    cpu=1
  fi
elif [ $# -gt 2 ]; then
  usage; exit
else
  opt="hoge"
  cpu=1
fi

#=== read inputfile ===#
read_input
case $reorder in
  ".true." | ".TRUE." | "T" | "t")
    reorder_check="TRUE"
    ;;
                                *)
    reorder_check="FALSE"
    ;;
esac

#=== ABORT ===#
trap 'abort 1 $COMNAME' 1 2 3 9 15

#=== Make directories ===#
make_dir

#=== preprocess ===#
if test $opt = "-all" ;then
  echo $NPREFAST...
  rm -f $TMP_FILE
  if [ $domain -ge 2 ]; then
    n_loop=$domain
    id=1
    for ((id=1; id<=$n_loop; id++))
    do
      echo "$NPREFAST $id  > $TMP_FILE$id &"
      $PREFAST $id  > $TMP_FILE$id &
    done
    wait

    i=1
    for ((i=1; i<=$domain; i++))
    do
      cat $TMP_FILE$i >> $TMP_FILE
      rm -f $TMP_FILE$i
    done

  elif [ $domain -eq 1 ]; then
    $PREFAST
    echo ""
  else
    echo "ERROR: It is wrong that total number of domain in $INPUT."
    exit
  fi

elif test $opt = "-n"; then
  echo $NPREFAST...
  rm -f $TMP_FILE
  n_loop=`expr $domain / $cpu`
  id=1
  i=1
  for ((i=1; i<=$n_loop; i++))
  do
    var=`expr $cpu \* \( $i - 1 \) + 1`

    id=$var
    j=1
    for ((j=1; j<=$cpu; j++))
    do
      echo "$NPREFAST $id  > $TMP_FILE$id &"
      $PREFAST $id  > $TMP_FILE$id &
      id=`expr $id + 1`
    done
    wait
  done

  if [ `expr $id - 1` -lt $domain ]; then
    while [ $id -le $domain ];
    do
      echo "$NPREFAST $id  > $TMP_FILE$id &"
      $PREFAST $id  > $TMP_FILE$id &
      id=`expr $id + 1`
    done
    wait
  fi

  i=1
  for ((i=1; i<=$domain; i++))
  do
    cat $TMP_FILE$i >> $TMP_FILE
    rm -f $TMP_FILE$i
  done

elif test $opt = "-e" ;then
  echo $NPREFAST...
  rm -f $TMP_FILE
  $PREFAST -e

elif test $opt = "-metis" ;then
  echo $NPREMETIS...
  rm -f $TMP_FILE
  $PREMETIS

elif test $opt = "-fsi" ;then
  make_dir_fsi
  echo $NPREMETIS...
  rm -f $TMP_FILE
  $PREMETIS FSI

elif test $opt = "-emetis" ;then
  echo $NPREMETIS...
  rm -f $TMP_FILE
  $PREMETIS -e

elif test $opt = "-efsi" ;then
  make_dir_fsi
  echo $NPREMETIS...
  rm -f $TMP_FILE
  $PREMETIS -eFSI

else
  echo $NPREFAST...
  rm -f $TMP_FILE
  $PREFAST
fi

#=== reorder ===#
case $reorder_check in
  "TRUE")
    echo $NREORDGRID...
    $REORDGRID
    echo $NREORDINDX...
    $REORDINDX
    ;;
esac

exit
```

I tried running a shell script but the following error appears:

[gakubu@localhost Kenkyuu]$ pre.sh

/home/gakubu/FaSTAR2019/Bridget2019/Kenkyuu/pre.sh: line 8: /home/gakubu/FaSTAR2019/Bridget2019/Kenkyuu/script.func: There is no such file or directory
/home/gakubu/FaSTAR2019/Bridget2019/Kenkyuu/pre.sh: line 30: set_variables: command not found
/home/gakubu/FaSTAR2019/Bridget2019/Kenkyuu/pre.sh: line: read_input: command not found
/home/gakubu/FaSTAR2019/Bridget2019/Kenkyuu/pre.sh: line: make_dir: command not found

...

[gakubu@localhost Kenkyuu]$

```
enter code here
```

What does this mean and how do I fix this?

Comment: Please share the contents on pre.sh

Comment: Please show us _at the least_ line 8 of the script in question (i. e. `pre.sh`).  Without seeing the script it's impossible for us to give a meaningful explanation of the source of the errors.  If I had to guess (which, given the lack of context, I do), it looks like the script is trying to `source` a library script that defines functions; this is failing; and subsequent calls to the functions the script is expecting to be defined are failing because it was unable to run the initial `source`.

Comment: How do I check the contents of the script?

Comment: @MorpokiaIjitsavy use the cat command to view contents of the file, in your case `cat pre.sh`

Comment: Thanks. Sorry, I had to figure out how to paste in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script has, on line 8, the following code:

```
. ${FASTAR_DIR}/"script.func"
```

This sources a file an a particular directory.  This file probably contains shell function definitions.  The file is not found, according to the error message, and the effect of not finding this file is later that the functions that it defines are not found (these are the "command not found" errors that you get).

The file `script.func` is assumed to be available in the same directory as the script itself.  If you have moved the script into where it's currently located, but forgotten to move the `script.func` file with it, then this would be the cause of the error.

I'm not going to comment further on the script itself other than to say that its use of unquoted variable expansions makes it very brittle, and possibly unsafe.

Comment: Would copy pasting the file to where I'm running the current program be ok?

Comment: @MorpokiaIjitsavy If you are able to use `cp` to copy the file (or `curl` to download it), that would be best.  Copying and pasting with the mouse would possibly not preserve whitespaces (tabs, especially) properly.

Comment: Ok, thanks! I think I got it, the script is functioning :)

Comment: 'its use of unquoted variable expansions makes it very brittle, and possibly unsafe.`

What do you mean? Would it damage the program?

Comment: @MorpokiaIjitsavy If the script, for example, is located in a directory with spaces in its name, I'd expect it to break in a way similar to what you saw. It may also be confused if the `IFS` variable is set to a set of digits (but the shell may be resetting this variable anyway).

Comment: I see. Yes that actually happened last time I tried to run a shell script and file not found error kept popping up.